# else for nothing found but not for EACH iteration line by line

Tags: python

I have some code below. I want to provide a else if NOTHING is found but not for each iteration. At the moment, the else works but for EACH line so:
NOTHING FOUND
NOTHING FOUND
..etc.

It should just say NOTHING FOUND if their is nothing found after iterating over the whole file line by line...the code below for context.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XSS Payload Search')
parser.add_argument('-p', action='store')
args = parser.parse_args()
key = args.p
with open("xss.txt") as f:
    found = False
    for line in f:
        if key not in line:
            line = line.rstrip()            
            found = True
    if found:
        print line
    else:
            print "Nothing Found!"
```

Comment: So, to clarify, you want it to print "Nothing Found!" if the file is empty?

Comment: I want to print nothing found only if my IF KEY NOT IN LINE comes back with no strings printed. I’m going to attempt the Boolean suggestion below but if it does work then I still don’t understand how.

Answer (score 2):

**UPD:** If the intention was to print each line that does not contain `key`, and print `"Nothing Found!"` when every line was fine, then please refer to [mnistic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53788452/4909228). The fix I described here would only print the first line (if found) that does not contain `key`.

The `else` clause of a `for` loop in Python executes only when the loop was not broken out of by `break` (for details see [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)). So the proper way to write your code would be:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XSS Payload Search')
parser.add_argument('-p', action='store')
args = parser.parse_args()
key = args.p
with open("xss.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if key not in line:
            line = line.rstrip()
            print line
            break
    else:
        print "Nothing Found!"
```

Furthermore, if you observe `"Nothing Found!"` printed for every line, then probably your indentation is not correct and the `else` clause was aligned with the `if` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply maintain a boolean variable to keep track of whether you've found the key or not:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XSS Payload Search')
parser.add_argument('-p', action='store')
args = parser.parse_args()
key = args.p
with open("xss.txt") as f:
    found = False
    for line in f:
        if key in line:
            line = line.rstrip()
            print line              
            found = True
    if not found:
        print "Nothing Found!"
```

Comment: IF NOT FOUND: 
still prints ALL the lines...in the text file when Nothing Found! should be the only thing printed.

Comment: For context sakes. Two Strings in the text file:
<script>alert("XSS")</script>
<script>alert(123);</script>
The below is not a mistake. Remember...(NOT IN LINE)
If I search XSS it prints the second.
If I search 123 it prints the first.
If I search ZZZ it shows ALL of the lines...when it should say NOTHING FOUND.

@jpp

Comment: My constant issue is that it is iterating all this logic per line which is what I wanted for searching but if nothing is printed(something matches for all lines) then it should be Nothing Found! ONCE. Not for each line that something matches for.

I hope all of this makes sense. If Key NOT IN line is why everything is "backwards" in a sense. Which is what I want.
@mnistic

Comment: Oops that should be `key in line` not `key not in line`. Fixed.

Comment: But, how do I get it to print "Nothing Found!" Once.
I've gotten it to print Nothing Found through EACH line but I want it to print ONCE if nothing is found. Not for each line it scans.

Comment: Have you tried the code in my answer? Copy / paste exactly as is

Comment: It did work. I apologize. Would you mind explaining why this worked?
Is it as expected? If there is nothing found then everything is false. And the if not found is then printed?(Bad way of explaining but you get my gist)
-EDIT
BETTER QUESTION.
How could I make it work with NOT IN as they program is based ALL around it. Without it then the purpose of everything I am coding fails.
I want to find payloads that DOESNT contain the provided string(s).

Comment: In theory, if I search for ZZZ. It should see that ZZZ is not in ANY script and then print "Nothing Found!" once.
As of now, when I do NOT IN; it just prints all the LINES in the text file.
I am actually reviewing this and wrapping my head around all of it to understand it better. I am not looking to be given answers but I do need assistance.

Comment: Im thinking its the PRINT LINE itself. I am searching for something thats NOT in it. So nothing with ZZZ appears so it prints all the lines.
Would it be easier to validate input to arguments only found within the lines?
@mnistic

Comment: -Updated Code
I thought the updated code in the original post would work but it only posts the last line no matter what...